# How can I ignore dist folder in .gitignore file?

Tags: git, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, gitignore

I want to ignore the `dist` folder. So when there is a change in the `dist` folder, it doesn't appear in the `commit`

In the .gitignore file, there had exist `/dist` like this :

```
.DS_Store
node_modules
/dist
```

But why when there are changes it still appears?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should add trailing slash instead `dist/` Did you already commit this folder ?

Comment: @Hurobaki It does not work. I have committed this folder before

Comment: You have to ˋgit rm -r dist ˋ to tell Git that you don’t want to track it anymore

Answer (score 58):

With Git if you commit a file or folder, Git will continue to track it even if you put it inside your `.gitignore`. Because `.gitignore` just prevent untracked files from being added.

To stop tracking you have to remove it from Git index

```
git rm -r --cached <folder> // git rm -r --cached dist
```

It will keep the folder on your local but it will not being tracked anymore.

For folder in `.gitignore` the correct format is `dist/` with trailing slash

Comment: Is there any way for it to persist? I have to do it literally every time I make a new build

Answer (score 9):

Check the format

```
.DS_Store
node_modules
dist/
```

Comment: It does not works

Comment: It worked for me, thanks